# How can I separate `<style>` from `<Window.Resources>`?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a lot of `<Style>` in `<Window.Resources>`.
How can I separate `<Style>` from `<Window.Resources>`?
Do I have to make a new `Window` file and use `<Application.Resources>`?

I also have a lot of those.

in my `<Window.Resources>`. Is it also possible to separate those?

Comment: External resources are a common thing. Did you make ANY research prior asking this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add those styles in ResourceDictionary and use it where ever required. You can add application level or Window Level.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/03/creating-and-consuming-resource-dictionaries-in-wpf-and-silverlight.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35346/Using-a-Resource-Dictionary-in-WPF

Answer (score 1):

You can create a ResourceDictionary file. It's just a xaml where you can put styles, control templates etc. See here for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc903952(v=vs.95).aspx

You can then attach this dictionary to your project in app.xaml.